# I2C, SPI and Python Libraries with Raspberry Pi 4b

Tags: rpi.gpio, i2c, python-3, wiringpi, gpiozero

I've been working with RPi.GPIO so far but I have had issues with PWM and edge detection, which are well known issues with RPi.GPIO, anyway, after some research I'm considering using a different library.

As I'm fairly new to the Pi world, there are some questions which I can't seem to find a clear answer to regarding these libraries and their pros/cons, I am familiar with certain differences such as RPIO being an extension of RPi.GPIO and wiringPi being a C based library:

- I quite like I2C, but the concept is quite new to me and I am unsure with how they interact with other libraries. Will using a library such as GPIOzero make it difficult to use I2C? From what I understand with GPIOzero you are limited to the devices that are supported, although I have seen that GPIOzero has pin library abilities. Is it possible to use I2C through these, such as importing PiGPIO into GPIOzero (is that right?), or does SMBUS work in conjunction with any library?
- In your experience, which is your favourite library and why? Which gives you more control and has less issues? PiGPIO, GPIOzero, RPIO, Rpi.GPIO, wiringPi?
- How does I2C compare to SPI, and which is better?
- Which library works best in conjunction with Arduinos, in your experience?
- Which library works best with the Pi 4b right now?
- Should I just stick with Rpi.GPIO?

Comment: This question is too general. I suggest you investigate gpiozero